# What is the purpose of the crc function in php

Tags: php

I have a variable

```
   $offset = abs(crc32($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) % 500);
```

and I do not understand it's place in the script. All it seems to do is generate a random number based on the server name (e.g. www.example.com). Is that a correct interpretation of this variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

crc32 creates a [Cyclic redundancy check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) of the name, and then moding by 500 further reduces it to a number between 0 and 499.  The first part is basically a signature of the server name - it's not a random number exactly (in it's original form CRC could be used to rebuild data that got corrupted), it's being used more like a hash here.  The second part is reducing the size/scale of that hash so that every server that visits gets a number between 0 and 499.  The hope is that it's rare that number is the same for two servers, although there's no real guarantees.

Comment: hang on, why would the number change? The script will be run on my server, which has a fixed server name: www.example.com. So are you saying when users visit my site they will be assigned different $offset variables? Because they are visting from different servers?

Comment: No it'll always be the same for your server, but if you move servers, or rename it, then the number will change.  It's hard to comment on the point without knowing the whole script, but basically it appears to allow the code to either (a) identify you've moved servers or (b) run on multiple servers at once storing in a single database & identifying the source.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it makes a number between 0 and 499 which only differs if the server name differs.

- Crc32 gets an numeric checksum from a string.
- % 500 makes it between -499 and 499.
- abs makes negative numbers positive.